# How to update the property member variable of a managed bean?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a member variable in a managed bean, and this member variable is tied to the component in XHTML with a getter and setter. If I set the member variable in a function call, when the getter of this member variable is trigger, this member variable will still hold the old value. May I know how could I update this member variable so that the component could get the latest updated value?

The manage bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "myBean")
@SessionScoped    
public class MyBean {
  public boolean show = false;

  /** getter and setter **/

  public void theFunc() {
     this.show = true;
  }
}
```

XHTML code

```
<h:panelGroup id="Panel_1" rendered="#{myBean.show == true}">
   ...
   Some rubbish here
   ...
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup id="Panel_2">
   <h:commandLink action="#{myBean.doFunc}">
      <f:ajax event="action" render="Panel_1"/>
      <h:outputText value="XX" />
   </h:commandLink>
</h:panelGroup>
```

From this sample, the `show` variable is showing false even though `theFunc()` has already set to true.

**Update on 06 Oct 2012**
I have remove commandButton and replace with commandLink, I think it should be fine in term of usage.

Comment: Can we see some code? Type of the variable, the kind of component it's related to, getters & setters, that kind of stuff...

Comment: Still no code where you set the variable.

Comment: when your theFunc() gets called? it should be called before the call to getter of show property. how do you make sure that?

Comment: the show variable was set in theFunc(). theFunc() is call within the JAVA code. See my updated code.

Comment: Is `@SessionScoped` from `javax.faces.bean` package? If it's from `javax.enterprise.context` package, then the `@ManagedBean` behaves like `@NoneScoped` and is thus recreated on every single `#{myBean}` expression evaluation. Further, the answers posted so far are assuming ajax, but you don't seem to be using that anywhere. Please confirm.

Comment: I am using javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean, and I have rework on my code to use ajax to update `Panel_1` but still the rubbish in `Panel_1` is not show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your methods **return type** and **name** if you want it to be invoked.

Change this

```
  public void theFunc() {
     this.show = true;
  }
```

to this

```
  public String doFunc() {
     this.show = true;
     return null;
  }
```

otherwise this action can not work.

```html
   <h:commandLink action="#{myBean.doFunc}">
```

then update **parent of your panel** like this

```html
<h:panelGroup id="parentPanelGroupId">

    <h:panelGroup id="Panel_1" rendered="#{myBean.show}">
        ...
        Some rubbish here
        ...
    </h:panelGroup>

</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup id="Panel_2">
   <h:commandLink action="#{myBean.doFunc}">
      <f:ajax render="parentPanelGroupId"/>
      <h:outputText value="SHOW/HIDE PANEL 1" />
   </h:commandLink>
</h:panelGroup>
```

**NOTE:**

use

> rendered="#{myBean.show}"

instead of

> rendered="#{myBean.show == true}"

Comment: It's indeed PrimeFaces-specific. Kerem is apparently mixing standard JSF with PrimeFaces.

Comment: yeap too much primefaces development made me forget standards :) corrected answer with render attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
<h:panelGroup id="toUpdate">

    <h:panelGroup id="Panel_1" rendered="#{myBean.show}">
        ...
    </h:panelGroup>

</h:panelGroup>

<h:commandButton action="#{theBean.doCalculation}">
    <f:ajax render="toUpdate" />
</h:commandButton>
```

There are 2 things to note:

1. You need to wrap `<h:panelGroup id="Panel_1">` inside another `<h:panelGroup>` or something eles which is always rendered. Otherwise, if the `show` variable is initially `false`, the ajax update may not work since JSF renderer cannot find the the component with `id="Panel_1"` when you use `<f:ajax render="Panel_1" />`.
2. `rendered="#{myBean.show}"` is good enough :P. Since `show` is a boolean variable, you don't need `rendered="#{myBean.show == true}"`.

Comment: Ya, I am using this method. But my problem is when I have the `show` variable updated inside the theFunc.theFunc(), regardless of setting it to true or false, lets assume the initial value is false, then I set it to true, then you will the getter of `show` variable is return true, not false. I think this must have something to do with the session has already run far far far away.